# Programmatically click a button using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this button:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick span12 reg-form-control validate[required]">
<button id="control-qid13228" type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-bootstrap" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="qid13228">
    <div class="filter-option pull-left">3 of 4 selected</div>&nbsp;<div class="caret"></div>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 249px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 92px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="max-height: 237px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 80px;">
        <li rel="0" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" onclick="update_reg_multi_click('qid13228','basketball');" style=""><span class="text">basketball</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
        <li rel="1"><a tabindex="0" onclick="update_reg_multi_click('qid13228','baseball');" style=""><span class="text">baseball</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
        <li rel="2" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" onclick="update_reg_multi_click('qid13228','football');" style=""><span class="text">football</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
        <li rel="3" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" onclick="update_reg_multi_click('qid13228','hockey');" style=""><span class="text">hockey</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried to click it programmatically using JQUERY

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#control-qid13228").click();
});                     
    </script>
```

I've also tried a trigger click:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#control-qid13228").trigger("click");
});                     
    </script>
```

Neither seem to work. Clicking with my mouse, of course, works fine. Any ideas?

Just a heads up, this is part of an attempt to address a different issue I'm having with bootstrap-select, addressed in this script in progress.

```
        function update_reg_multi_click(id,myvalue) 
        {
            //
            var main_id = $("#" + id);
            var main_id_control = $("#control-" + id);
            var main_id_option = $("#" + id + " " + ">" + " " + "option");
            var main_id_value = $(main_id).val();               
            var this_div = $(this);
            if(main_id_value != null){
                var main_id_value_list = $("#" + id).val().toString();
                var test_if_in_list=main_id_value_list.toLowerCase().indexOf(myvalue) >= 0;
                if(test_if_in_list){
                    //alert('in list');
                    $(main_id_option).each(function() {
                        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
                    });                         
                    var newlist = remove_reg_val(main_id_value_list,myvalue,",");                           
                    $.each(newlist.split(','), function(){
                      var option_to_set = $("#" + id + " " + "option[value="+this+"]");
                      $(option_to_set).attr('selected','selected');
                    });
                    $(main_id).selectpicker('refresh');     
                }
                else{
                    //alert('not in list');                     
                    $(main_id_option).each(function() {
                        $(this).removeAttr("selected");
                    });                             
                    //alert(main_id_value_list);
                    var newlist = main_id_value_list + ","+myvalue;
                    //alert(newlist);
                    $.each(newlist.split(','), function(){
                      var option_to_set = $("#" + id + " " + "option[value="+this+"]");
                      $(option_to_set).attr('selected','selected');
                    });
                    $(main_id).selectpicker('refresh');                                 
                }
            }
            else{
                var newlist = myvalue;
                $.each(newlist.split(','), function(){
                  var option_to_set = $("#" + id + " " + "option[value="+this+"]");
                  $(option_to_set).attr('selected','selected');
                });
                $(main_id).selectpicker('refresh');                                                           
            }                           
        }
```

Here is the select I'm trying to address:

```
<select name="qid13228" id="qid13228" class="selectpicker span12 reg-form-control validate[required]" data-style="btn-bootstrap" multiple="" data-selected-text-format="count&gt;2" style="display: none;">

<option value="basketball" onClick="update_reg_multi_click('qid13228','basketball');" selected="selected">basketball</option>

<option value="baseball" onClick="update_reg_multi_click('qid13228','baseball');">baseball</option>

<option value="football" onClick="update_reg_multi_click('qid13228','football');">football</option>

<option value="hockey" onClick="update_reg_multi_click('qid13228','hockey');" selected="selected">hockey</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with inline JavaScript?

Comment: It's part of an attempt to address an issue with bootstrap-select I'm currently dealing with.

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem.  Please construct a concise demo in a jsFiddle.

Comment: The inline JS is messy and shouldn't be required when using jQuery.  So let's assume your attempt at fixing another issue through the usage of inline `click` handlers is misguided... what happens when you remove every single inline `onClick` and focus your attention on good, clean jQuery code?

Comment: @VIVINPALIATH in case you weren't aware, jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: It's not valid markup to have a `<div>` inside of a `<button>`

Comment: @self thanks, but I am well aware of that. I was referring to OP's use of inline JavaScript along with jQuery.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Add a small timeout:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){

        $("#control-qid13228").click();


    },1);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/46my242x/1/

or try:

```
$("#control-qid13228")[0].click();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/46my242x/2/

This is a similar question: [jQuery.trigger('click') not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928915/jquery-triggerclick-not-working)

Comment: In my case I needed higher timeout. I set it to 500.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#control-qid13228").click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});                     
</script>
```

Comment: I've amended the question so you can see the larger issue. I trigger the click after I run $(main_id).selectpicker('refresh'); and it doesn't toggle the button.