# How to get JQuery.trigger('click'); to initiate a mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers, eventtrigger

I'm having a hard time understand how to simulate a mouse click using JQuery. Can someone please inform me as to what i'm doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<a id="bar" href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Don't click me!</a>
<span id="foo">Click me!</span>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#foo').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('#bar').trigger('click');
});
```

Demo: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8AVau/)

when I click on button #foo I want to simulate a click on #bar however when I attempt this, nothing happens. I also tried `jQuery(document).ready(function(){...})` but without success.

Comment: `jQuery trigger` only works if any 'jQuery click` event is added. Otherwise you will not be able to do anything by this way;

Comment: This is a security measure built into the browser. See @Blazemonger's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element

Comment: @san.chez Interesting, thanks for the info, didn't knew about this security measure before!

Answer (score 309, accepted):

You need to use `jQuery('#bar')[0].click();` [to simulate a mouse click on the actual DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) (not the jQuery object), instead of using the `.trigger()` jQuery method.

Note: DOM Level 2 `.click()` doesn't work on [some elements in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925153/jquery-click-works-on-every-browser-but-safari). You will need to use a workaround.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Used this to click the next tab on jQuery ACF fields: 

$('.next').click(function () {
    $('#primary li.active').next().find('.acf-tab-button')[0].click();
});

Comment: thanks. It works in desktop. But on mobile (android chrome) it doesn't. any suggestions?

Comment: For some reason this destroys the hash in the current URL.

Comment: if one of the hrefs on the <a tag is '#', that would do it.  <a normally redirects to a different URL.  You must stop it with ev.preventDefault() and ev.stopPropagation() before your click handler returns.  OR, use some other tag besides <a; you can attach click handlers to anything that's visible.

Comment: That seems not to work anymore (tested on Safari, Firefox)

Answer (score 59):

You just need to put a small timeout event before doing `.click()`
like this :

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#btn').click()}, 100);
```

Comment: Works perfect if you are trying to simulate a click when the page loads.

Comment: This solved my problem too, thanks.  None of the other solutions worked reliably.  My code showed a modal, then simulated a click on a tab.  Why is the delay necessary?  I had to use 500ms to be on safe side.

Comment: Brilliant! This solved my issue. Why is timeout required? Nothing else worked for me.

Answer (score 36):

This is JQuery behavior. I'm not sure why it works this way, it only triggers the onClick function on the link.

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#foo').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('#bar')[0].click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Not irritating at all. `trigger()` is intended to execute the click event **JavaScript** portion. It's very similar to creating a `function var() {}` thats re-used multiple times.

Answer (score 24):

See my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8AVau/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#foo').on('click', function(){
         jQuery('#bar').simulateClick('click');
    });
});

jQuery.fn.simulateClick = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if('createEvent' in document) {
            var doc = this.ownerDocument,
                evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, doc.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else {
            this.click(); // IE Boss!
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I would wrap the `this.click();` in an `else if(this.click)`

Comment: Why are you passing the string `'click'` into the `simulateClick` function? It doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: @clayRay - yes, I agreed with you. It was made many years ago keeping in mind to make dynamic based on params. But later on I have just tried to make the solution of current requirement. Thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 15):

May be useful:

The code that calls the Trigger should go **after** the event is called.

For example, I have some code that I want to be executed when #expense_tickets value is changed, and also, when page is reload

```
$(function() { 

  $("#expense_tickets").change(function() {
    // code that I want to be executed when #expense_tickets value is changed, and also, when page is reload
  });

  // now we trigger the change event
  $("#expense_tickets").trigger("change");

})
```

Comment: Ahhh that was my problem too! Was baffled as to why the `trigger()` wasn't working. Turns out I had the trigger code set ABOVE the function it was calling - so the hook wasn't actually in place. Doh!

Answer (score 5):

jQuery's `.trigger('click');` will only cause an event to trigger on this event, it will not trigger the default browser action as well.

You can simulate the same functionality with the following JavaScript:

```
jQuery('#foo').on('click', function(){
    var bar = jQuery('#bar');
    var href = bar.attr('href');
    if(bar.attr("target") === "_blank")
    {
        window.open(href);
    }else{
        window.location = href;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this that works for me:

```
$('#bar').mousedown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically not an answer to this, but a good use of the accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20928975/82028) to create next and prev buttons for the tabs on jQuery ACF fields:

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    $('#primary li.active').next().find('.acf-tab-button')[0].click();
});

$('.prev').click(function () {
    $('#primary li.active').prev().find('.acf-tab-button')[0].click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried top two answers, it doesn't worked for me until I removed "display:none" from my file input elements.
Then I reverted back to .trigger() it also worked at safari for windows.

So conclusion, **Don't use display:none; to hide your file input** , you may use opacity:0 instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this:

```
$(function() {
 $('#watchButton').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't simulate a click event with javascript.
jQuery `.trigger()` function only fires an event named "click" on the element, which you can capture with `.on()` jQuery method.

Comment: _"You can't simulate a click event with javascript"_ - [Yes you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click).

Comment: Wrong... you can simulate a click event with javascript/jquery and you can capture trigger click event with .click without on.