# calling click event of input doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have a input, type of file, with `display:none` and there is a button.
after clicking the button, the input's event should be fired. In IE, Chrome and Firefox it works but not in Safari!

```
var elem=$('<input id="ajxAttachFiles" name="fileUpload" type="file" style="display: none;"/>');
    if($("#ajxAttachFiles").length==0){
        elem.prependTo(".ChProgress");
    }
$("#ajxAttachFiles").click();
```

there is no error in console. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928915/jquery-triggerclick-not-working) but nothing.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").on('click',function(){
          $("#ajxAttachFiles")[0].click();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ajxAttachFiles" type="file" style="display:none;">
<button id="btn" type="button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Which build of Safari are you using?

Comment: @Sprottenwels 5.1.7(7534.57.2)

Comment: Does it work if you don't hide it with `display: none`?

Comment: @dfsq I just tested. no difference

Comment: So basically click event is not triggered in Safary on input type file. Actually it's not supposed to work in other browsers to, I'm surprised it works for you in Chrome.

Comment: Click event in safari on input type file will work if it is not hidden and click() is called out of user interaction (e.g inside onclick handler etc).

Comment: @amitesh is correct - this has nothing to do with the visibility of the input control and everything to do with the invoking context.  You must call input.click() from within a ux event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is completely solved. The point is element of `input[type=file]` must not be `display: none`. Look at sample below:

```js
function click(el) {
  // Simulate click on the element.
  var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
  evt.initEvent('click', true, true);
  el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

document.querySelector('#selectFile').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var fileInput = document.querySelector('#inputFile');
  //click(fileInput); // Simulate the click with a custom event.
  fileInput.click(); // Or, use the native click() of the file input.
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="inputFile" type="file" name="file" style="visibility:hidden; width:0; height:0">
<button id="selectFile">Select</button>
```

Comment: The visibility is not the reason this works but the fact that it's being invoked from a click event.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the click event on the DOM element rather than the jQuery object. That should work in all browsers.

```
 $('#ajxAttachFiles')[0].click();
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById('ajxAttachFiles').dispatchEvent( new Event('click') );
//for IE < 9 use microsoft's document.createEventObject
```

```js
var elem=$('<input id="ajxAttachFiles" name="fileUpload" type="file" style="display: none;"/>');
    if($("#ajxAttachFiles").length==0){
        elem.prependTo(".ChProgress");
    }

$("#ajxAttachFiles").on('click',function() {
  alert( 'click triggered' );
});

$("#ajxAttachFiles")[0].click();

//an alternative:
var event = new Event('click');
document.getElementById('ajxAttachFiles').dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ChProgress">Will be added here</div>
```

Comment: You probably have duplicate IDs. Be sure not to leave out the [0]. Would you please create a demo.

Comment: It just shows the alert and doesn't show `browse file window`

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input