# jQuery click event not call in safari for hidden field

Tags: jquery, browser, safari, hidden-field

I have a issue in `safari` when click event call for `hidden field`.

Its work in `firefox` and `chrome` but not worked in `safari`.

below code:

```
<a href="#" class="aaa">aaa</a>
<a href="#" class="bbb" style="display:none;">bbb</a>

<script>
$('.aaa').click(function(){
 $('.bbb').click();
});
</script>
```

In safari, for bbb event not call but work in FF and chrome.

any one have a idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of above my question.

```
<a href="#" class="bbb"  style="visibilty:hidden;width:0;height:0">bbb</a>
```

I found answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501221/calling-click-event-of-input-doesnt-work-in-safari)