# jQuery trigger event is not executed

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to trigger a click on an input field on page load. The input field is placed within a form.

HTML:

```
<form>
.... other fieldsets ....
<fieldset>
<ul class="chosen-choices">
<li class="search-field">
<input class="default" type="text" style="width: 147px;" autocomplete="off" value="Choose a category…">
</li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
.... other fieldsets ....
</form>
```

jQuery

```
<script>     
    $('.default').trigger('click',function() {
            console.log( '.trigger() called.');
        });
    console.log('done');        
</script>
```

The jQuery trigger is not run, as nothing appears in console, besides the 'done' log.

I want to trigger a click on the input field with class "default".

Comment: working fine with event listener: http://jsfiddle.net/0bzuqoee/ also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928915/jquery-triggerclick-not-working

Comment: `.trigger()` doesn't have a callback argument.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the problem, that your code does not bind a click-event to the input element in question you have not made sure that the action happens *after* the page is fully loaded.

Place your code into the onload-section (`$(function(){...})`) and also bind a function for the click-event (`$('.default').bind(function(){...});` and it will work. The appended `.click()` (without an argument) is actually a short form of `.trigger('click')` and does exactly the same, see here (make sure to open the console to see the output generated):

```js
$(function(){ // anything in this function gets executed *after* the DOM has finished loading
  $('.default').click(function() {
     console.log( '.trigger() called.');
   }).click(); // same as: .trigger('click');
      console.log('done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chosen-choices">
<li class="search-field">
<input class="default" type="text" style="width: 147px;" autocomplete="off" value="Choose a category…">
</li>
</ul>
```

This solution works without explicitely using `trigger()`, but it triggers the click-event that was previously bound to the DOM element by calling `.click()` without an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the jquery code is put last in the page just before  see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105327/should-jquery-code-go-in-header-or-footer)

Or you can use the defer="defer" tag if this helps with your formatting
(please not that firefox doesn't support the defer attribute

Answer (score 0):

.trigger() triggers the click. It doesn't handle the event that's fired. You need to have an event handler for that.

@cars10's code neatly does both. I'd add this as a comment to that answer but I don't have enough rep yet.