# the trigger event isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an href that I want to be clicked automatically on page load. This is the HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="foo">YahOO</a>
```

and this is the script part:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#foo").trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

But when I load the page nothing happens. Am I using the wrong ajax lib or what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Also dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811122/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-link-using-jquery

Comment: it's still not working..i saw that response but it's not working for me...

Comment: and i want to activate the href when the page loads not when I click something..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery('#foo')[0].click(); to simulate a mouse click on the actual DOM element (not the jQuery object), instead of using the .trigger() jQuery method.

Note: DOM Level 2 .click() doesn't work on some elements in Safari. You will need to use a workaround.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Post from [jQuery.trigger('click') not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928915/jquery-triggerclick-not-working)

Comment: ... and why not use redirection? What sense does it make to click a link outside of testing purposes?

Comment: @chrispolzer probably OP is just experimenting for later delegating/duplicate-nesting the click to an image or other elements. There's lots of use-cases.