# auto click a link when page loads doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, dom

I have a page for redirect purpose, I want to redirect user to another page once it hits this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Open App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("test"); //this shows up.
            $('#openApp').click(); //this button is not clicked.
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" id="openApp">redirect</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the redirect happen once this page is load. But the click function is not fired. I have to click the link by myself to redirect to google.com.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928915/jquery-triggerclick-not-working

Comment: This works exactly as you have it in Chrome, FF, and IE11 in this JS fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/q7hqadzL/  Can you demonstrate different behavior in a JS Fiddle?

Comment: If possible, an .htaccess or server side redirect may be preferable to using javascript.

Comment: @KingJulian 's link solved my problem. simply change it to `$('#openApp'')[0].click();`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally wouldn't give you an alternative as an answer, but looking at your comments, it looks like you're just trying to redirect.

You can use `window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');` for that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');
});
```

See also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to trigger a `click` event without any user interaction. In other words, if the function being called wasn't called from a user interaction, the click event will not get triggered.

In your case, simply update the `window.location` attribute:

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: you mean remove click function, add `window.location = ('http://www.google.com', '');` ? It doesn't work, it keeps refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exwjr4fq/) mate, added script is

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //this shows up.
        $('#openApp')[0].click(); //this button is not clicked.
    });
```