# Trigger automatic download file based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a success page on `drupal 8` to download a file once redirected. Is there anyway to trigger downloading the file automatically based on a condition

For example if the page has an attribute `download` `<a class="cta download-pdf" download="" href="/downloads/aim-brochure-mib.pdf">Download Brochure</a>` inside the markup it would automatically download the file based on the address. Was thinking of using jquery/javascript to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

After redirecting that page inside document ready you can trigger your anchor tag.

```
$(function() {
//Check condition if any
$('.download-pdf').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I've tried this recently it doesn't seem to trigger the anchor link and found the cause a solution for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928915/jquery-triggerclick-not-working