# how to click a button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the DOM :

```
<div class="form-actions">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save device</button>
</div>
```

I want to use Jquery to select the button and click on it? 
I tried using : `jQuery(".btn btn-primary").click()`
which is not working

Comment: Please google your title and tell me what comes up

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically click a button using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732664/programmatically-click-a-button-using-jquery)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. The problem/solution here involves selector syntax.

Comment: Youre right, didn't read enough

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to select an element with both classes, therefore your selector should be `.btn.btn-primary`.

```
$('.btn.btn-primary').click();
```

You were trying to select a element with class `.btn-primary` that was a descendant of a `.btn` element.

Comment: Incidentally, the OP's selector `.btn btn-primary` doesn't reference a class named "btn-primary" due to the lack of a preceding dot.

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is incorrect; because both classes are on the same element you need to separate them by `.` with no spaces:

```
jQuery(".btn.btn-primary").click()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the jQuery trigger() method to trigger the behaviour of an existing event handler.

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
example:

<button id='testButton'>Test</button>

<script>
$(function(){
   $('#testButton').on('click' , function(){
        alert("I've been clicked!");
   });

   //now on another event, in this case window resize, you could trigger
   //the behaviour of clicking the testButton?

  $( window ).resize(function() {
        $('#testButton').trigger( "click" );
  });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the following:

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Use `$(".btn-primary").trigger("click");`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Just incase you did not learn yet, you can always define an Id for the button and use it this way:

```
<div class="form-actions">
  <button id="mybutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save device</button>
</div>


 $('#mybutton').click(function(){
    //your code goes here
 });
```

Comment: That's really not necessary, plus it doesn't show the OP what he was doing incorrectly.

Comment: @j08691 may I learn what OP stands for ? I shared just incase he may not be aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

$( window ).load(function() {

$(".btn-primary").trigger('click');


});